# AWS braket compiler simulation

Tags: amazon-braket

Is there a way to see the compiled circuit on Braket (Rigetti,IonQ,Oxford) without actually sending the circuit to the QPU?
I would like to analyze how the circuit is compiled before sending it for simulation.

Comment: Have you tried to use print() function?

Comment: I would like to have the compiled circuit, not the one I've written.
So I'd want to know what physical gate is executed on what qubit

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function in the Braket to get the compiled circuit without running it on the QPU. You can only check your written circuit with `circuit.instructions` or `circuit.to_ir()` methods.